# toggle angular css class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

I am trying an toggle the class 'not-compatible':false to 'not-compatible':true using angularjs:

```
    <div class="col status" style="margin-left: 63px;margin-right: 74px; width: 190px">
        <label class="title">Radius</label>
        <img src="assets/images/BOTTOM SCREEN/OPERATION BOARD/SVG/button UP enable.svg" ng-click="myFunctionUp()/>
        <div id="myDiv" class="status-bar" ng-class="{'not-compatible':false,'in-progress':false} ">
            <label class="number-spolier">1000<span>m</span> </label>
            <span><span></span></span>
        </div>
        <img src="assets/images/BOTTOM SCREEN/OPERATION BOARD/SVG/button DOWN enable.svg" ng-click="myFunctionDown()/>
    </div>
```

when the img(either first or second) is clicked to change the class to true of the div "myDiv".

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like,
In HTML:

```
<div class="col status" style="margin-left: 63px;margin-right: 74px; width: 190px">
        <label class="title">Radius</label>
        <img src="assets/images/BOTTOM SCREEN/OPERATION BOARD/SVG/button UP enable.svg" ng-click="myFunctionUp()/>
        <div id="myDiv" class="status-bar" ng-class="{'not-compatible':isCompatible,'in-progress':false} ">
            <label class="number-spolier">1000<span>m</span> </label>
            <span><span></span></span>
        </div>
        <img src="assets/images/BOTTOM SCREEN/OPERATION BOARD/SVG/button DOWN enable.svg" ng-click="myFunctionDown()/>
    </div>
```

In controller:

```
    $scope.isCompatible = false;
    $scope.myFunctionDown = function(){
      $scope.isCompatible = true;
      //$scope.isCompatible = !$scope.isCompatible; //Or toggle like this
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set flag on your scope indicating if image has been clicked. You can add this line of code to `myFunctionUp` and `myFunctionDown` functions to set scope variable indicating that img has been clicked:

```
$scope.imgClicked = true;
```

and then just use this variable in ng-class like that:

```
ng-class="{'not-compatible': imgClicked}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a scope variable instead of `false` in your expression

```
{'not-compatible':false,'in-progress':false}
```

See https://plnkr.co/edit/ekIrDxH9DswG3UJzRiVT?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Try this example might help, actually you need to use the variable instead of directly setting true/false in ng-class

```
https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass
http://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/qlLED
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-class should not have "false", but should have the name of the model's variable. For example, if MyFunctionDown() sets "classStatus = 'Fred'" then you could have something like ng-class="{'not-fred':classStatus !== 'Fred', 'is-fred':classStatus === 'Fred'}"